# How to upgrade InfoPath forms in Forms Server from WSP

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, infopath, infopath-2007, infopath-forms-services

I have a SharePoint workflow built with Visual Studio that implement a custom task form via InfoPath and deployed to Forms Server.  My problem is that anytime I need to tweak the form, I cannot get the new version deployed to the server without completely uninstalling & reinstalling the entire solution.  The usual upgrade solution route does not seem to work with publishing the changed form to Forms Server.  This is really bad because it means I would kill any workflows in progress if I uninstall the solution.

Surely there must be a way to get the form updated with the standard upgrade solution approach, right?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new uniquely named wsp solution that only contains the task form changes. This has worked for other people that have the same requirement.

Check out this link for a more detailed explaination:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointworkflow/thread/471154ac-acb2-496b-ac83-f4efb7b6e530